# How do you see a characters energy level in Skullgirls iOS?

Tags: skullgirls-mobile

So in Skullgirls on iOS how can you see a character's energy level? It seems like the only place to see it is when you are in an event page or once you've run out of energy. Sometimes I will see a red lightning bolt but that's usually when its asking me to refill energy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the energy level of all characters by going to the Collection screen. You can get to this screen by tapping the Home icon and then tapping the box labeled "Collection". The energy levels are represented by yellow lightning bolts and will be empty once used.

For example, I just used Peacock and Big Band in two back-to-back fights that cost 2 energy, so they're both missing 4 energy, while Cerebella has full energy.

[image: energy levels]